# calculating gravitational movement of 2 objects python

Tags: python, graphics, pygame, physics, game-physics

I have 2 particle objects, each has an x position and a y position and a mass. I want to move the objects 30 times every frame in a realistic way. [Newtonian gravity]. I move the objects by adding a value to the x and y pos every frame, how would I calculate this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because - math/physics question, not a programming question

Comment: I wouldn't close it only because it is math/physics.  Believe it or not, some programmers deal in those topics.  However, even though it references pygame, (which has physics engines to which this question would be applicable), it's a very broad question.  We either need more information regarding the type of movement you want, or some code showing how far along you are.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to use the equations provided [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/one-dimensional-motion/kinematic-formulas/a/what-are-the-kinematic-formulas). In particular you'll want to use equations that solve for Δx. I'm not going to go into more detail because explaining kinematics is a rabbit hole that doesn't really have an end I could reach in one answer.